# Bad latency on PLC (TP-Link) home network

Tags: networking, ping

I noticed very bad latency (ping times) when playing Rocket League on my PC connected to the internet over PLC ([power-line communication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power-line_communication), i.e. ethernet over power) -- *60 ms* when my gaming PC is the only one sucking data and around *120 ms* with other clients. Using the command line to ping 8.8.8.8 for testing purposes gives me a *24 ms* ping and even pinging the EU Rocket League servers directly gives me no more than *40 ms* of ping.

I had the idea to try different packet sizes, and I was dead-on with that guess. **Pinging my own router over PLC gives a RTT of *3 ms* if the packet's size is 975 bytes, but a RTT of *22 ms* if the packet's size is 976 bytes**.

Both packet sizes have a RTT of around *0.5 ms* when I connect to the router directly using an ethernet cable, which makes me think it's not an issue with the router but the PLC.

As this seemed to map exactly onto the concept of MTU ([maximum transmission unit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_transmission_unit)), I tried setting the MTU on my PC to higher and lower values than the default 1500 using the command `sudo ifconfig enp3s0 mtu 1500`. Sadly, no improvement in Rocket League ping. It also [seems to NOT be possible to set the MTU of my router manually](https://en.avm.de/service/fritzbox/fritzbox-7430/knowledge-base/publication/show/432_Manually-adjusting-the-MTU-size-for-DSL-connections/). I also downloaded TP-Link's settings utility for the adapters (tpPLC) and couldn't find an MTU setting there either.

Technical information:

- device connecting router to power line: **TP-Link TL-PA4020P**
- devices connecting power line to PCs: **TP-Link TL-WPA4220**
- "gaming" PC running **Linux Mint 18.3** and **Windows** (high latency occurs on both)
- residential gateway device: **Fritz!Box 7490** (did a factory reset today so it's all default settings)
- as is clear from the Fritz!Box, I'm in **Germany** (mains electricity varies between countries)

**How can I eliminate the *19 ms* penalty when sending a "large" packet over PLC?** Additionally, should I worry about the Rocket League servers (for small packets) having worse ping than 8.8.8.8?

Comment: I don't have enough for an answer, but I'd investigate [buffer bloat](https://www.bufferbloat.net/projects/)

Comment: Buffer bloat would be relevant for the multiple clients part, but not the PLC part, which is my main problem, right?

Comment: Note that the emulated Ethernet MTU might not necessarily correspond to the Homeplug/PLC connection's MTU.

Comment: Yeah. But I downloaded TP-Link's settings utility for the adapters (tpPLC) and couldn't find an MTU setting. Let me add that to the question.

Answer (score 0):

According to this
[IEEE](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/4231751) scientific paper, the smaller size you adjust for MTU, the better  i.e. less packet loss.
Obviously, you need to config the same MTU on every LAN adapter within your network for above mentioned approach to work out properly.
Not really suitable for copying big files, but could work in RT apps like small chunks in video streaming or P2P.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I don't really think the paper is related to the problem I'm experiencing. And as I said I already set the MTU to a lower value on my Linux and Windows PCs without success.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should also adjust same MTU size in PLC adapters, as well as Fritbox router, otherwise it won't work.
It is not sufficient by reducing MTU on client computers, rather every element of your network.
A low MTU has its pros and cons.